# Change detection on delta tables using Synapse

Tags: azure-synapse, delta-lake, change-data-capture

I am trying to build a process of moving changed data from "Silver" Tables to "Gold" only processing changed records in Silver using Spark in Synapse , but its proving near impossible.

There is a feature in Delta Lake (v2 and higher) called "Change Data Feed" and it is exactly what I am looking for (https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-change-data-feed.html) , but there seems to be one part missing in Synapse, and that is the Table Valued function called "table_changes" that allows you to query changes for a given Delta Table that has had the option for change detection set on.

Synapse allows you to activate Change Data Feed , you can describe the history of the delta table, it just seems that the Table Valued function called table_changes has not been implemented.

I am looking for any advice, or alternatives in Synapse for detecting changes in Delta Tables.

To reproduce , create a Spark Notebook in Synapse and execute the following code (PySpark)

**Create a basic silver table in Delta**

```
countries = [("USA", 10000, 20000), ("India", 1000, 1500), ("UK", 7000, 10000), ("Canada", 500, 700) ]
columns = ["Country","NumVaccinated","AvailableDoses"]
spark.createDataFrame(data=countries, schema = columns).write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("silverTable")
```

**Check that you can query the newly created table**

```
%%sql
SELECT * FROM silverTable
```

**Set the setting for enabling changing data feed**

```
%%sql
ALTER TABLE silverTable SET TBLPROPERTIES (delta.enableChangeDataFeed = true)
```

**Lets add in some changed data for the purposes of extracing said data**

```
new_countries = [("Australia", 100, 3000)]
spark.createDataFrame(data=new_countries, schema = columns).write.format("delta").mode("append").saveAsTable("silverTable")
```

**Query the changed table to view changes**

```
%%sql
-- view the changes
SELECT * FROM table_changes('silverTable', 2, 5) order by _commit_timestamp
```

*This produces an error :*

Error: could not resolve `table_changes` to a table-valued function; line 2 pos 14
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$AnalysisErrorAt.failAnalysis(package.scala:42)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.ResolveTableValuedFunctions$$anonfun$apply$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$2(ResolveTableValuedFunctions.scala:37)

Comment: I tried the same thing in synapse and databricks. It worked in Databricks. But It doesn't work in Synapse. AFAIK, It is not supported

Answer (score 2):

I tried writing the below function. It works for now:-

```
def fn_table_changes(arg1,arg2, *argv):    
    tablename = arg1    
    list1 = arg2    
    list2=''    
    for arg in argv:    
        list2 = argv[0]    
    if isinstance(list1, int) == True:    
        if isinstance(list2, int) == True:    
            df = spark.read.format("delta").option("readChangeFeed", "true").option("startingVersion", list1).option("endingVersion", list2).table(tablename)    
            return(df)    
        else:    
            #print("st version")    
            df = spark.read.format("delta").option("readChangeFeed", "true").option("startingVersion", list1).table(tablename)    
            return(df)    
    else:    
        if list2 != '':    
            #print("st&en timestamp")    
            df = spark.read.format("delta").option("readChangeFeed", "true").option("startingTimestamp", list1).option("endingTimestamp", list2).table(tablename)    
            return(df)    
        else:    
            #print("st timestamp")    
            df = spark.read.format("delta").option("readChangeFeed", "true").option("startingTimestamp", list1).table(tablename)    
            return(df)
```

and then we can call this:-

```
df=fn_table_changes('silverTable', 1)    
df.createOrReplaceTempView("table_changes")
```

Answer (score 1):

You are experiencing this behavior because [support for CDF in SQL queries should come with Delta Lake 2.3.0](https://github.com/delta-io/delta/releases/tag/v2.3.0). Quoting the [Delta Lake blog](https://delta.io/blog/2023-05-02-delta-lake-2-3-0-released/):

> Support reading Change Data Feed (CDF) in SQL queries Delta Lake
> supports a Change Data Feed (CDF) which tracks row-level changes made
> to a Delta table over time. The CDF can be great for building
> intelligent incremental updates or as an audit log.

What is interesting to note is that this blog also mentions that CDF "was only easily accessible via the Spark DataFrameReader APIs in Python and Scala."

I ran a test, and indeed this works on my Spark cluster node with Delta Lake version 2.2 (edit: this also explains why your solution worked):
[image: Output from pyspark cell execution]

Here's a snippet of my cluster config:

[image: Cluster config]

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same script in synapse environment and databricks environment. It is not working in Synapse environment.
Instead, you can retrieve data on the operations, user, timestamp for each write to a Delta table by running the `history` command.

```sql
%%sql
DESCRIBE  HISTORY silverTable;
```

[image]

This gave the history of the changes done in silverTable.